# Configuring multiple instances of mysqld on almalinux

Tags: mysql, systemctl

I've been trying to setup multiple instances of mysqld on an almalinux box.
I can't get the `systemctl start mysqld@replica03` statements to recognize the associated options setup in the `/etc/my.cnf` file.
If I change the `[mysqld@replica03]` or `[mysqld@replica04]` to `[mysqld]` it works and uses the appropriate datadir and port.  As soon as I use `[mysqld@replica03]` and `[mysqld@replica04]` in the `/etc/my.cnf` file it uses the default `/var/lib/msyql` datadir and options instead of the ones I specified

I have run

```
systemctl enable mysqld@replica03
systemctl enable mysqld@replica04
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

/etc/my.cnf file:

```
[client-server]

[mysqld@replica03]
server_id=3
port=3306
datadir=/var/lib/mysql_replica03
socket=/var/lib/mysql_replica03/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql_replica03/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld_replica03/mysqld.pid

[mysqld@replica04]
server_id=4
port=3307
datadir=/var/lib/mysql_replica04
socket=/var/lib/mysql_replica04/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql_replica04/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld_replica04/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Look at `systemctl cat mysqld@.service`. There should be something there that triggers the `mysqld` to look at different configurations. It may not the the simple mapping to the `--defaults-group-suffix=@%i` that you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  

I tried systemctl edit mysqld.service to override 
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-group-suffix=.%I --basedir=/usr
with
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-group-suffix=@%I --basedir=/usr
It didn't seem to fix it.
I also tried 
systemctl edit mysqld@.service
Failed to get load state of mysqld@.service: Unit name mysqld@.service is neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name.
I'm quite sure how i should be overriding it.

Comment: I think you would have better help on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use the default configuration and use `[mysqld.replica03]` as the section in the config file for example. Start using `mysqld@replica03.service` as the systemd service name.

Answer (score 0):

When you need multiple instances, and you're using `systemd` to achieve it, the [server option groups](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#server-option-groups) configuration is the way to go.

The comment you made on your question shows that the suffix used is prefixed with a dot.

`ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-group-suffix=.%I`

So the server groups should be rewritten to

```
[mysqld.replica03]
server_id=3
port=3306
datadir=/var/lib/mysql_replica03
socket=/var/lib/mysql_replica03/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql_replica03/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld_replica03/mysqld.pid

[mysqld.replica04]
server_id=4
port=3307
datadir=/var/lib/mysql_replica04
socket=/var/lib/mysql_replica04/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql_replica04/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld_replica04/mysqld.pid
```

Another important observation is that the order in configuration files matters. Theses `replica` servers definitions need to be parsed after main `[mysql]` section.

`my_print_defaults` will help you with it:

```
$ my_print_defaults --defaults-group-suffix=.another mysqld
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql
--socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
--log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
--pid-file=/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
--datadir=/db/another/mysql
--socket=/db/another/mysql/mysql.sock
--log-error=/db/another/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
--pid-file=/run/mariadb/mariadb-another.pid
$
```

If your OS has a `/etc/my.cnf.d/` directory, as mine does, you will need to sort the filenames in order to accommodate this requirement.

As I'm using `mariadb`, and I have a `/etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf`, my `another` server group is on a file named `zz-another.cnf`, making sure it will be parsed after `mariadb-server.cnf`.